# How to compare multiple excel sheets containing stock prices?

Tags: excel, scripting

So hi I'm new to excel scripting and I am facing a pretty tough nut to crack due to my friend begging me to help him with a economics task so basically they have to use historical data from 2018 to purchase stocks and they have to have maximum profit the one with the most profit gets an A , they have about 100k USD at the start and if my intel is good one of the best guys in his class whos doing it manually earned about a million so I think that with excel I could maybe earn 3-4 million and win the game , my idea was to  ask my friend to send the data they've received in an Excel file and use a vba script to compare the delta beetwen 1-2 days worth of info and buy every 1-2 days to maximise profit , is it doable?

Comment: Ya but too much work that way. You could use MS Access and import all the excels as tabels. Then create relationship query and that way you can compare data. More advanced to this is MS SQL Server. Also if you want to see patterns etc then MS Power BI can be handy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , Im pretty green when it comes to access and BI but it seems like the only real solution here , considering  my idiot friend told me about this yesterday and it's due today anyways thanks

Comment: Sure, it's doable.